# Why Is my "flex-wrap" property not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is my **flex-wrap** property not working? Have I made any mistakes in the code?

```css
.container {
  border: solid black 2px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="box-1">First Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-2">Second Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-3">Third Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-4">Fourth Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-5">Fifth Box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: reduce the width of the container to see it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have reduced the height and width and it works

```css
.container {
  border: solid black 2px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="box-1">First Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-2">Second Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-3">Third Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-4">Fourth Box</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-5">Fifth Box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Write down a little what exactly has been changed and why

Answer (score 0):

If you try to write more sentences it will work. Or see it in the responsive situation, play with the width, try 300px;

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the width between 350 to 400 px. This might help with the issue.Check W#Schools for more understanding